# how can i get a string with country, city and street name from Latitude and Longitude

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can I do a function by asking Lat and Lon to find the state name, street name and street number or just the full Lat and Lon address

Comment: You can't by default. You'll need to find a 3rd party library to do this.

Comment: ^ I would recommend the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google maps, you can try to use `Geocoder` to get the address based on coordinates. Just like this:

```
var currentLatitude = ...;
var currentLongitude = ...;

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

var latlng = { lat: currentLatitude, lng: currentLongitude };

geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        // address
        console.log(results);
    } else {
        console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
});
```